# Multiple POST request using ASIFormDataRequest synchronous

Tags: ios, post, asihttprequest

Basically my app will retrieve an array of Data from database and upload it to the server(one at a time/ one after the other). I want to stop all the request when one of the data failed to upload (please check on the comments).

Code:

```
// 0 means need to upload to server
NSString *condition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"isUploaded=\"0\""];
// array of ID on my database to be uploaded
NSArray *arrayOfID = [Registered distinctValuesWithAttribute:@"registeredID" predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:condition]];

// loop every index and upload it to server
for (int i=0; i<arrayOfID.count && !isBreak; i++) {
            // get the entity using ID
            NSString *condition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"registeredID=\"%@\"",[arrayOfID objectAtIndex:i]];
            Registered *entity = [Registered getWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:condition]];
            if (entity) {
                __weak ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
                [self setRequest:request withEntity:entity]; // set delegate,POST,etc.
                [request setCompletionBlock:^{
                        // returns dictionary (success/failed)
                        NSDictionary *dict = [[request responseString] JSON];
                        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
                            // set IsUploaded to 1 after successful upload to server
                            [entity setIsUploaded:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
                            [Registered commit];
                            // Any necessary ideas that would make my code better 
                            // and continue the POST request and proceed to the next entity???  
                        }
                        else {
                            // I want to cancel all the request here and get out to this loop
                            }
                 }];
                 [request setFailedBlock:^{
                       // I want to cancel all the request here and get out to this loop
                 }];
                 // start startSynchronous
                 [request startSynchronous];

        } else {
            [GlobalMethods ShowAlertView:@"Database Error" message:@"Please try again later"];
            isBreak=YES;
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak your code slightly and use the provided ASINetworkQueue class. From [the documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use/%22the%20documentation%22), if one request in the queue fails, by default the rest are cancelled automatically.

You can use a `break` statement to immediately exit a loop. However, because the callbacks are asynchronous, putting one in the failure block will not have the effect you're looking for...assuming the failure block is fired in reaction to a server response and not something in the API itself, that loop will complete and fire off all your requests--and the enclosing method will return--*long before* any of your requests has the time to come back from the server and call its failure block (this is networking code, after all). So you're not going to be able to use a failure block to interrupt the creation of additional requests in the loop; that's not how asynchronous calls work.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is that I'll put every request to ASINetworkQueue? BTW the link you provide is broken. TY

Comment: Sorry about the broken link, try this: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ASIHTTPRequest/1.8.2/Classes/ASINetworkQueue.html

Yeah, what I meant to say is that might be sort-of a way to accomplish what you're looking to do...but it's still quite likely that additional requests would be scheduled. Asynchronous calls are essentially "fire and forget"...execution will continue before they return, so you don't really have a way to break.

Comment: I think you might consider simply handling errors gracefully and not focusing so much on canceling further requests...so what if they all return failure? Just respond to the first failure you get.

Comment: Ahhh I see Thank you. do you have any links or snippets for ASINetworkQueue with POST method request also?